# useState array gets cleared on updating within socket.io event

Tags: reactjs, sockets, next.js, socket.io

I have a chat application similar to whatsapp using socket.io. It has a event `msg-receieved` which is emitted from backend whenever a new message is received at backend.
Whenever this event is emitted, frontend try to update an useState array called `userAllMessages`. This array also stores the previous messages of the user which we get from a POST call to API on first render of page.

I don't know why the `socket.on` event listener always clears the `userAllMessages` array even I use the spread operator or pass a callback function the the `setUserAllMessages`.

```
function ChatContainer() {
  const loggedInUserEmail = useSelector(state=>state.loggedInUser.emailId);
  const selectedChatUser = useSelector(state=>state.selectedChatUser.selectedChatUser);
  const socket = useSelector(state=>state.socket.socket);
  const [userAllMessages, setUserAllMessages] = useState([]); 

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(!socket)return;
    socket.on('msg-receieved',async (data)=>{
      console.log("message received: ",userAllMessages);
      setUserAllMessages([...userAllMessages,data]); // problem arises here. 
       // even this method is not working: (prev)=>[...prev,data]
    })
  },[])
  useEffect(()=>{
    getUserAllMessage();
  },[selectedChatUser])
  const getUserAllMessage = async ()=>{
    let payload = {
      from:loggedInUserEmail,
      to:selectedChatUser?.email
    }
    try {
      const response = await getMessage(payload);      
      if(response.data.status === 200){
        console.log("user messages",response.data);
        setUserAllMessages(response.data.messages);
      }
      else{
        console.log("Error while getting user messages: ",response.data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
       console.log("Error while getting user messages: ",error);
    }
  }
  return <div className="overflow-auto custom-scrollbar relative w-full flex-grow h-full">
    <div className="bg-chat-background bg-fix h-full w-full absolute top-0 opacity-5 z-0"></div>
    <div className="mx-10 my-6  z-40">
    <div className="flex w-full">
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-end gap-1 w-full overflow-auto">
        {userAllMessages.map((message,index)=>(
          <div key={index}
          className={`flex ${message.senderId === loggedInUserEmail ? "justify-end":"justify-start"}`}
          >
              <div className={`text-white px-2 py-[5px] text-sm rounded-md flex gap-2 items-end max-w-[45%] ${message.senderId === selectedChatUser?.email ? "bg-input-background":"bg-outgoing-background"} `}>
                  <span className="break-all">{message?.message}</span>
              </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>;
}
```

It's my first time using socket.io. I don't know why this is happening. Anyone knows what's wrong with my code?